# RegEx to handle upper and lowercase of some characters

Tags: java

```
public class BioHomework {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    if(args.length < 2) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("two args required");
    }
    String sequence = args[1];
    if (!sequence.toLowerCase().matches("[atgc]{10,20}")){
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("second arg should be 'atgc' string between 10 and 20 characters");
    }
    if ("u".equals(args[0])) {
      System.out.println(sequence.toUpperCase());
    } else if ("l".equals(args[0])) {
      System.out.println(sequence.toLowerCase());
    } else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("first argument must be either 'u' or 'l'");
    }

  }
}
```

How can I get dna sequence to be printed in upper and lower case by giving command line argument.Above code is giving me only messages nothing else.

Comment: Execute the program using `java BioHomework u DNAString` or `java BioHomework l DNAString`

Comment: I know how to execute the program i need a c g t in upper or lower case whose length should be between 10 to 20.

Comment: Which messages is it giving you?

Comment: Oh ok, then change the RegEx to `[aAtTgGcC]{10,20}`

Comment: I can't see how that would change anything, since it's converting the string to lowercase before matching against the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the RegEx in order to accept the characters in upper or lowercase. From

```
[atgc]{10,20}
```

To

```
[aAtTgGcC]{10,20}
```

Comment: Unfortunately  not working I am getting message exception in thread main IllegalArgumentException("two args required");

Comment: I am not able to figure out what is wrong in above code.Please let me know how to get dna sequence a c g t in upper or lower case when printing command line arguments u or l.

Comment: If I understand you well, you need to send 2 parameters to your Java program: 1st parameter will be letter `u` or `l`, second will be your DNA String to check. Call the program using `java BioHomework u ACGCTGATGA` (just as an example).

Comment: For clarification ,how can i write a program that will take two command line arguments.first should be the letter 'u' or 'l' and e, and the second should be a DNA sequence (a c g t in any case) of between 10 and 20 characters.  Use regular expressions to validate both arguments, and if either or both arguments are invalid, print appropriate messages and end the program, otherwise print the given sequence in upper case if the first argument is 'u' or print the given sequence in lower case if the first argument is 'l'. String class has the appropriate methods for changing case.

Comment: The above code is not mine, I have taken from this site as it looked OK to me, but not working in my case.